# how to check if a file is signed or not?

Tags: windows, digital-signature, self-signed, jar-signing

There is a list of jar files, that I want to know if they are digitally signed, they are on a windows machine.
I tried to right click on one of the jars, but couldn't see anything related to digital signature, is there a way from windows to detect if file is signed or not?

Regards,

Comment: If you right-click on a file to check signatures in Windows, it will check for Microsoft Authenticode signatures. This is different from Java signatures.

Comment: can you elaborate more about the difference between the 2? and if I want to know if the jar is signed (whether java signature or mircosoft signature), how can I check that? @MSalters

Comment: The main difference is that Authenticode is for Windows executables and JAR signing is for Java executables. I was just explaining why Windows did not show a signature on your JAR file - it looks for a totally different type of signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a JDK installed, you can run `jarsigner -verify` from CMD or PS prompt, which will check the signature if it is present or tell you if it is absent, or just run `jar tf file.jar META-INF` and look for filenames like $signer.SF; for a multiversion jar with lots of clutter in META-INF, either search positively for .SF files with a tool like `findstr` (or `-match` in PS) or negatively exclude all versions/ files.

If you mean with *only* Windows, a jar file is really a zip file with certain restrictions, and Explorer (since Vista IIRC) understands zip files. Change the extension from .jar to .zip, then 'open' the file as a folder and look in META-INF for $signer.SF file(s). But this is a manual process so you can't really drive it from a list in a file, if that's what you mean.